# Serializing/Deserializing a List of DataContracts

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontractserializer, datacontract

Is there anyway to serialize a List of datacontracts? I have created a datacontract for the list, something like this:

```
[DataContract]
class ItemList<T>
{
    public ItemList()
    {
       items=new List<T>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public List<T> items;    
}
```

I have 3 clases Config, Config_V1, Config_V2 with the attribute [Name="Config"] what let me use versioning between the 3 versions of the Config class. So I would like to serialize and deserialize between ItemList of this Config clases. I have tried something like:

```
ItemList<ConfigData_V1> l = new ItemList<ConfigData_V1>();
l.items.Add(config);
WriteObject<ItemList<ConfigData_V1>>("serialization.bin", l);
ItemList<ConfigData_V2> l2;
l2=ReadObject<ItemList<ConfigData_V2>>("serialization.bin");
```

But I get an error when deserializing with the ReadObj that says that it is expecting a list of ConfigData_V2 but it found a List of ConfigData_V1. Wouldn't it just use the versioning of ConfigData clases to resolve this conflict?

Comment: I think it is the serialization of the strongly-type `List<T>` itself (not its members) that is the problem.  Try, as lame as it is, an untyped `List`.

Comment: @jonnyGold you are not right. List<T> is serializeble (IEnumereble<T> not). Issue in other place.

Comment: @RrefCat I didn't say it wasn't serializable.  I said that it is the fact that a `List<ConfigData_V1>` was serialized and he is attempting to deserialize it into a `List<ConfigData_V2>`.  They aren't the same `Type`, so it won't work.  He has to do it untyped.

Comment: The untyped things did not work either. Anyway thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you deserialize an object (`List<Contract1>`) it adds metadata to specify that a-the data is part of a List and b - the containing object is `Contract1`.

If you look at the actual XML that is written you will see this in the nodes.

As a result, when you attempt to do a read into `List<Contract2>` you break the definition of the model because you told it the contained data was `Contract1` but you trying to read `Contract2`.

There is an attribute `[KnownType(Type)]` which could potentially help you if you state that Contract2 is a known type of `Contract1` though that really breaks the entire concept of contracts......

Comment: Yes, you're right, it breaks the concept of contracts. Do you know of an alternative way to do this?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do.  I cannot think of a normal situation where you would serialize Data then deserialize into a new contract version.  UNLESS -- ooohhh -- you had data persisted in one version and then updated your application without saving that serialized data.  Messy.  Very messy.  If that is the case then I'd write a Q&D that deserializes Contract1 then serialized Contract2.

Comment: If you will always be doing this stuff with different contracts, then I'd make all contracts inherit to a base contract that contains the main data you need.  You could save / retrieve that data but you would not get the uniqueness of each individual contract.  :(  Kind of a tough nut and definitely a catch 22.